# Access values of JS object by key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really doubt my mind right now and am pretty confused.

I'm building a little chat application, just to expriment with some stuff...

For that, I have a MySQL Database with a table just storing the messages with an ID, the content of the message, the userid and a timestamp.

On the page to display the chat, I then do an ajax request to my backend, which returns the data from the database like so:

```
$messages = $db->exec('SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 50');
echo json_encode($messages);
```

So what I'm getting from there the last 50 messages, encoded in JSON.

On the page, I then receive that and parse them:

```
messagesParsed = JSON.parse(messages);
```

So now, what I've got in that variable is this (shortened a bit)

```
[
    {
        "ID": "68",
        "content": "oi",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:42"
    },
    {
        "ID": "67",
        "content": "io",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:42"
    },
    {
        "ID": "66",
        "content": "oibioboib",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:42"
    },
    {
        "ID": "65",
        "content": "iob",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:41"
    },
    {
        "ID": "64",
        "content": "b",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:41"
    },
    {
        "ID": "63",
        "content": "boi",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:41"
    },
    {
        "ID": "62",
        "content": "oibio",
        "uid": "4",
        "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:41"
    }
]
```

Then, I'm looping through this array in reverse, with the goal to display the latest message at the very bottom of the page:

```
for(var i = messagesParsed.length; i>=0; i--){
                    message = messagesParsed[i];
                    console.log(message);
                  }
```

So far so good, I now got this as a result (stored in the `message` variable)

```
{
    "ID": "32",
    "content": "fn",
    "uid": "4",
    "time": "2021-07-16 13:29:24"
}
```

Here comes the strange part: I want to only display the content of the chat message (at first) and have tried like 20 different variations of getting the content, so within the for loop, I did something like:

console.log(message.content);
console.log(message["content"]);
console.log(message[content]);

And some other crazy stuff, but in the end, I'm not getting the console to output the value. Only thing I'm getting there is  `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong? It's not like the first time I try to access something in a JS object, but it seems like I'm just completely lost on this one.

Comment: You're starting the reverse loop outside the bounds of the array. Use `var i = messagesParsed.length - 1`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh cmon... I already though I was completely stupid, didn't think about that actually... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you are trying to start at an element that is out of range (messagesParsed.length). Try using the below - it worked for me on jsbin with your test data provided

```
for(var i = messagesParsed.length - 1 ; i>=0; i--){
                    message = messagesParsed[i]
                    console.log(message.content)
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You are making an extra iteration here
As you are starting from the index which is equal to the array's length

```
for(var i = messagesParsed.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    message = messagesParsed[i];
    console.log(message);
}

//Otherwise, you can also use
for(var message of messagesParsed){
    console.log(message.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace var i = messagesParsed.length to var i = **messagesParsed.length - 1** or better use forEach loop